# Agregar botones de editar y eliminar en cada una de las filas de mi tabla usando JS y Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

Mi duda es como puedo hacer que se agreguen botones de editar y eliminar a cada una de las filas de mi tabla, ya que esta se rellena por medio de un formulario que se visualiza por medio de una ventana emergente (Bootstrap modal), este es el código que tengo:

*HTML*

```
<div class="table-responsive">
<table id="Usuarios" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover">
<thead>
<tr class="table-header">
  <th>ID</th>
  <th>Número de empleado</th>
  <th>Área</th>
  <th>Nombre</th>
  <th>Apellido</th>
  <th>Tipo de Usuario</th>
  <th>Opciones</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr role="row" class="odd">
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>


<div class="container">


<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Add_Us_New">
  Agregar Usuario Nuevo
</button>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="Add_Us_New">
  <div class="modal-dialog"> 
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button tyle="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">X</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Agregar Usuario</h4>
          </div>
          <div>
            <p>
              <label>ID Empleado</label> <br>
              <input id="idemp" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="ID Empleado"><br>
            </p>
            <p>
              <label>Nombre</label> <br>
              <input id="nombre" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Nombre"><br>
            </p>
            <p>
              <label>Apellido</label> <br>
              <input id="apellido" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Apellido"> <br>
            </p>
            <p>
              <label>Número de Empleado</label> <br>
              <input id="numemp" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Número"> <br>
            </p>
            <p>
              <label>Área</label> <br>
              <input id="area" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Área"> <br>
            </p>
            <p>
              <label>Tipo de Usuario</label> <br>
              <input id="tipo_usuario" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Tipo de Usuario"> <br>
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
           <button id="btn_guardar" class="btn btn-success" onclick="guardar()">Guardar</button><br>
           </div>  
        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
```

*JS*

```
function guardar(){

    var _idEmp = document.getElementById("idemp").value;
    var _nombre = document.getElementById("nombre").value;
    var _apellido = document.getElementById("apellido").value;
    var _numemp = document.getElementById("numemp").value;
    var _area = document.getElementById("area").value;
    var _tipoUs = document.getElementById("tipo_usuario").value;

    var fila="<tr><td>"+_idEmp+"</td><td>"+_nombre+"</td><td>"+_apellido+"</td><td>"+_numemp+"</td><td>"+_area+"</td><td>"+_tipoUs+"</td></tr>";

    var btn = document.createElement("TR");
    btn.innerHTML=fila;
    document.getElementById("Usuarios").appendChild(btn);


     if (confirm('¿Agregar usuario nuevo?')) {
       document.form1.submit();
       document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
    }
}
```

Eh intentado poniendo botones en

```
 var fila="<tr><td>"+_idEmp+"</td><td>"+_nombre+"</td><td>"+_apellido+"</td><td>"+_numemp+"</td><td>"+_area+"</td><td>"+_tipoUs+"</td></tr>";
```

Ya que esto es lo que se visualiza y agrega a mi tabla cuando relleno el formulario pero no me manda los datos a la tabla, solo así sin agregar botones me aparecen agregados los datos.

Soy novata en esto y agradecería me ayudaran.

Comment: Tu problema es que al momento de añadir un botón los datos no se muestran, pero si quitas el botón sí lo hace? Eso es?

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera así es, cuando agrego los botones no se agregan los datos que yo ingreso en el formulario.

Comment: agregando : "<td><button>editar</button></td>" antes de "</tr>" no funciona?

Comment: @ChristianCarrillo Nop, ya lo agregué y al dar guardar en mi formulario no se agregan los datos a mi tabla, ni me aparece el mensaje de confirmacion que puse.

Comment: a mi me funciona, debes estar comiéndote un cierre de etiqueta o algo, envía pm si no.

Comment: Lo mismo que @ChristianCarrillo, replique tu codigo y me funciona agregando el botón al `td`. Como recomendación considera usar las etiquetas de [Javascript 6](https://uniwebsidad.com/tutoriales/las-nuevas-cadenas-de-texto-de-javascript-6) para mejor legibilidad del código y así te evitas concatenar

Comment: @ChristianCarrillo y PauloUrbanoRivera gracias por los comentarios, tal vez sí estoy escribiendo algo mal y no me he dado cuenta jaja

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tu variable fila debería ser:

```
var fila="<tr>"+
      "<td>"+_idEmp+"</td>"+
      "<td>"+_nombre+"</td>"+
      "<td>"+_apellido+"</td>"+
      "<td>"+_numemp+"</td>"+
      "<td>"+_area+"</td>"+
      "<td>"+_tipoUs+"</td>"+
      "<td><button>editar</button></td>"+
      "<td><button>eliminar</button></td>"+
      "</tr>";
```

o con la sintaxis moderna:

```
var fila=`<tr>
      <td>${_idEmp}</td>
      <td>${_nombre}</td>
      <td>${_apellido}</td>
      <td>${_numemp}</td>
      <td>${_area}</td>
      <td>${_tipoUs}</td>
      <td><button>editar</button></td>
      <td><button>eliminar</button></td>
    </tr>`
```

Comment: LISTO! Ya aparecen, ahora me queda hacerlos funcionales. Muchas gracia por la ayuda! :)